# Importing .NET assembly into Delphi fails

Tags: .net, delphi, .net-assembly, delphi-xe4, tlb

I am trying to import a .NET assembly into Delphi to create a "_TLB.pas" file, but I am receiving an error:

[image: Screen shot of error]

What is causing this error?

Is the .NET assembly not being built with the correct assembly attributes?

Is there a limitation on the .NET version (4.6.1) that XE4 can import?

The .NET assembly shown below was created with VS 2012 on .NET 4.6.1.

Using Delphi XE4, following these steps:

- Component -> Import Component -> Import a Type Library
- Click 'Add'
- browse to the .NET assembly.

When selecting the assembly, the error occurs.

After building the .NET assembly, I am successfully able to put it in the GAC (gacutil), register it in the assembly (regasm), and add it as a component in a COM+ application.

I have tried creating the `.tlb` with `regasm` and importing that, but the same error occurs.

ObjectCache.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.EnterpriseServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestObjectCache
{
    [Guid("7B1FEFFD-1569-404F-B7EB-6AAB903B8779")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IObjectCache
    {
        Boolean GetTrue();
    }

    [Guid("80C986C4-6B1F-4E3C-9B5E-13943DD1E1FD")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ProgId("ProgId.ObjectCache")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    public class ObjectCache:ServicedComponent, IObjectCache
    {
        public ObjectCache()
        {
        }
        public Boolean GetTrue()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

AssemblyInfo.cs:

```cs
[assembly: ApplicationActivation(ActivationOption.Server)]
[assembly: ApplicationName("Object Cache")]
[assembly: Description("Caches commonly used objects")]
[assembly: ApplicationAccessControl(false)]
```

Comment: I cannot say for sure but a "gut" feeling on this is that the .NET namespace 'EnterpriseServices' is preventing Delphi from being able to import its type library. If 'EnterpriseServices' is not used, InteropServices is still used, then the type library can be imported to Delphi. May be due to a Windows api not being available through 'EnterpriseServices'. If I get time to verify this I will update this post.

Comment: I just moved forward using InteropServices instead of EnterpriseServices.

Answer (score 1):

Run the Assembly through Visual Studio's `Tlbexp.exe` tool to generate a `.tlb` file, and then import that file into Delphi.

Otherwise, try using the importer's "Import .NET Assembly" option instead of the "Import a Type Library" option.

Comment: I get the same error attempting to import the .tlb generated from Tlbexp.exe as the .tlb generated from regasm.
Using "Import .NET Assembly" also failed but this option does not allow the creation of the _TLB.pas file.